# Why append dont work? how take specific columns from excel in one new excel Sheet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas.excelwriter

The problem is:
I want take from multi different excell(.xlsx) filles , specific ccolumns and save all this in a different excell-Sheet..
I can take DataFrame in my terminal but only save the last loaded .xlsx in my excell-sheet.
What i am doing wrong ? how can solve this problem?
Have pandas a simple command for this common problem?
I try many solutions from "stackoverflow" but i cant find the right way..

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    
    df_col=pd.DataFrame()
    
    print(df_col)
    
    i=0
    while i<len(files):
        # Import the excel file and call it xls_file
        xls_file = pd.ExcelFile(files[i])
        # Load the xls file's Sheet1 as a dataframe
        df = xls_file.parse()
        need_df = pd.read_excel(files[i], usecols=list_col_pros) 
        ########################################################
        # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
        df_col.append(need_df)
        ##########################################################
        # Returns column with label col as Series
        print(need_df)
        
        i=i+1
    
    ##########################
    
    
    print(df_col)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('all_pros.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    
    # Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
    df_col.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet')
    # Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
    writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this would work. I made some dummy files with column B titled "Starting Position"
But I think you should be able to change it to your filenames/columns easily.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_col=pd.DataFrame()

print(df_col)
files = ["1.xlsx","2.xlsx","3.xlsx"]
i=0
while i<len(files):
    # Import the excel file and call it xls_file
#   xls_file = pd.ExcelFile(files[i])
    # Load the xls file's Sheet1 as a dataframe
#   df = xls_file.parse()
    need_df = pd.read_excel(files[i], usecols="B") 
    ########################################################
    # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
    df_col[files[i]] = need_df['First Position'].values
    ##########################################################
    # Returns column with label col as Series
    print(need_df)
    
    i=i+1

##########################


print(df_col)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('all_pros.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
df_col.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet')
# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Comment: I try put "writer = pd.ExcelWriter('all_pros.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    
        need_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet')
    
        writer.save()" after the loop but the shame problem ...
can you help me?

Comment: If you put it after it means you are just writing it all once, at the end!

Let me try a code and then post it as a separate comment.

Comment: look and next try with append please

Comment: I think you are very close. Try 
df_col = pd.concat([df_col, need_df])

instead of append.

Comment: my friend it works perfect!!!!!!
Thank you very much...!!!! very useful...!!!!
one more thing ...
how can set index to be 0,1,2,3,4,5 (now is like 0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,1,2....)

Comment: Take a look at this:
[link]https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html